# Sympy type symbols to Python code

Tags: python, sympy, symbolic-math

I am trying to manipulate variables in `sympy`, so that after I can input them into a Python function which requires the input to be “normal” Python code. For example:

I would like to input (where x is a `sympy` symbol):

```
y = x**3 +  x**2 + 3*x +5
```

Then, in the same code I would later like to be able to insert `y` into another function, lets say:

```
OtherFunction(y)
```

where `y` is no longer the “type” sympy symbol, but rather interpreted as if I had directly input

```
OtherFunction(x**3 + x**2 + 3*x +5)
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Take a look at [`lambdify`](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/utilities/lambdify.html#sympy.utilities.lambdify.lambdify).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is already how Python works. When you define y as you show, you are creating a Python variable, y, that has the value of a SymPy expression. So if you call some function, passing y, you are actually passin the expression:

```
>>> y = x**3 +  x**2 + 3*x +5
>>> def foo(x):
...  print 'got',x
...
>>> foo(y)
got x**3 + x**2 + 3*x + 5
```